# The Schengen zone and how to count the 90 days as a tourist after a long term visa

Tags: visas, schengen, france, 90-180-visa-rules

I was in France on a student visa which expired July 2017. 
I exited France and entered the UK. 
From the UK, I entered the Schengen in Norway, July 10th, 2017.

Since then, I went back to the UK for a month, and then back to Norway, which is where I am now.

Since July, I have been in the Schengen for roughly 40 days.

In October, I need to enter France again for 90 days.

My question is, has the clock started ticking the second I entered the Schengen in Norway in July??

If I enter France from a non-Schengen country like the UK, does my clock start again for 90 days?

Am I screwed?

Answer (score 8):

The Schengen clock starts ticking on the *day* (not the second) you enter the Schengen area, other than a country you have a valid long-stay visa for.

It does not get reset by reentering the Schengen area.

If you have been in the Schengen area for 40 days since July 10, you now only have 50 days left to be in the Schengen area until and including January 5 2018 (which is when the 180 day period that started July 10 will end).

There is no way to change that, short of somehow getting a long-stay visa or residence permit from the Schengen country you want to spend additional days in. Which way you travel doesn't matter.